# How to use python to delete the latter part of the content in a test file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just as the picture below, there is a line `ENDMDL`. How can I use the `readline()` function and some basic loop to delete all the content after this line?

[image]

Comment: Voted to close because the post has no image.

Comment: @StudentT: 1. Image is there. 2. You don't have enough rep to cast a close vote right? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
file_path = 'your/file/path'

with open(file_path) as inf, open('outfile', 'w') as outf:
    for i in inf:
        if i.strip() == 'ENDMDL':
            break
        else:
            outf.write(i)
```

Comment: See, a basic `for` loop can do this in very simple way. I'd suggest you try something, if it doesn't work then ask question here (also remember that explain why doesn't it work). Because SO isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `tempfile` and use `shutil.move` to replace the original:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

from shutil import move

with open("your_file") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".",delete=False) as tmp:
    for line in f:
        tmp.write(line)
        if line.rstrip() == "ENDMDL":
            break
move(tmp.name, "your_file")
```